# acceptable use of python __init__ method

Tags: python, init

To my understanding, the **init** method in a class gets the class going by containing the lines of code that will be run when an instance of the class is created. My question is: how do I use the **init** method to manage the data in the class correctly? Currently, I am using the **init** method to call other methods in the class that will modify the data as I want.
For example:

```
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.setVar1()
        self.setVar2()
        self.math()
        print(self.result)
    def setVar1(self):
        self.var1 = 1
    def setVar2(self):
        self.var2 = 2
    def math(self):
        self.result = self.var2 - self.var1
instance = example()
```

Though this code is **working**, I want to make sure it is the proper way to use the **init** method.

Comment: This is fine; `__init__` is just another method, it can use more methods if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, @MartijnPieters, I wasn't sure exactly what to put into __init__ but now I know. :)